# Setting content-type header in axios when using FormData

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, content-type

I need to set custom content-type (of excel file instead of `multipart/form-data`) when sending file with FormData using axios but it's not working.

Seems like default content-type (`multipart/form-data`) from FormData is overriding my custom header, if I set data to null then content-type is set to what I specified.

Here is the code:

```
const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', fileList[0]);

        let config = { headers: { 'Content-Type': fileList[0].type };

axios.post(`url`, formData, config).then(response => {
            //
        }).catch(error => {
            //
        })
```

This is not working but if I send `null` as second parameter instead of formData then content-type will be set accordingly. I need to set correct content-type because API that I'm using is checking it.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: This doesn't make sense. If you are sending a formData object then you **are** sending `multipart/form-data` … even if the only part inside it is an Excel file. Why would you lie to the server about what you are sending?

Comment: @Quentin the API i'm using is checking content-type of sent file, is there any other way I can send this file to API with correct content-type then?

Comment: Is it checking the content type of the **file** or of the **entire request**? Each part of a multipart request has its own content-type.

Comment: @Quentin Error i'm getting is 
message: "FST_ERR_CTP_INVALID_MEDIA_TYPE: Unsupported Media Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary6gAi0jy3aT4qH5pu"

API request is for importing excel files
I don't know any other way to send excel file to API other than formData

Comment: If it expects you to send an Excel file then you should send an Excel file and not a multipart form data bundle containing an Excel file. (and off I go duplicate hunting)

Comment: i.e. Send `fileList[0]` and not a form data object.